# chcore command not taking effect

Tags: unix, aix, dump

I am trying to change the behaviour of where core dump files get written to, as described here:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/chcore.htm

However, when I log in again, even though the setting seems to have taken effect (testing through lscore), the core dump for a test process I execute are still written in current working directory of the process.

```
>lscore
compression: off
path specification: on
corefile location: /usr/local/cores
naming specification: on
```

What is strange, is that if I then perform "su -" to the same user, the core dumps are then written in the expected directory (usr/local/cores, not current working directory).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found the answer here:
https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1010900

Need to set UseLogin to "yes" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config